# How to make thw query by LIKE not case sensitive?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a query to seek data from SQLite for SEARCH realization in java project. I need that both variant with upper and lower first letters were true while making the query from SQLite. The query I make is such:

```
String sqlQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM city AS t1, region AS t2 ON t1.region_number = t2._id WHERE t1.name LIKE '%' || ? || '%';";
```

Then I put it in the next method:

```
  public Cursor fetchRecordsByQuery(String query) {
      return  myDataBase.rawQuery(sqlQuery1, new String[] {query});
  }
```

I need that the query was not case sensetive. That both results with lower case and upper case first buttons were true. How to make it? one thing - the symbols are russian.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, then you could do something like `lower(t1.name) LIKE (something in lower case)`

Comment: `LIKE` already ignores case, but only for ASCII characters.

Comment: It's not working.... :(